# how do i extract multiple substrings from a single string separated by space?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, character-encoding

i was trying to solve this problem  https://a2oj.com/p?ID=24

my initial code (only testing the input part)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int l;
        string input;
        cin>>l>>input;

        string texts[l];

        int c=0;
        for(int i=0;i<input.size();i++)
        {
            if(input[i]==' ')
                {c++;continue;}
            else
            {
                texts[c]=texts[c]+input[i];
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
            cout<<texts[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

its only scanning until it receives first ' '(space), and not other sub strings.

Comment: That's how `std::cin::operator>>` works. If you want to read an entire line consider using [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Answer (score 0):

You can use getline();

in this code i've used 't' as delimeter you can use space " " or whatever you want

**Example code**

```
#include <iostream.h>

void main()
{
   char line[100];
   cout << " Type a line terminated by 't'" << endl;
   cin.getline( line, 100, 't' );
   cout << line;
}
```